# can't add an events to a button in a storyboard

Tags: swift, xcode, xcode-storyboard

I know I can control drag from my button to my controller, but it looks like I should also be able to simply click the "+" button to add an action.  However, clicking the + doesn't seem to do anything

[image: storyboard actions]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After you tap on `+`, you need to drag that blue line into the code:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The plus is not intended to be clicked, it is intended to be dragged to the corresponding ViewController.

Open the assistant view:
[image]

Then choose "Automatic" and select your view controller:

[image]

Then you can drag from the Plus into the ViewController code.